# Remove leading zeroes in PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery

Thank you in advanced for everyone's help. I am relatively a novice at power query. I tried a few formulas but none worked.

All I am trying to do is if the value in column Customer PO starts with 00 or 0, it is removed/deleted.

[image]

= Table.TransformColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Customer PO",each if Text.Start(Text.From(*),2)="00" then""&Text.From(*) else _ }})

Tried this formula but it only adds in from of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: you seem to want to get rid of leading zeroes

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStepNameHere",{{"Customer PO", each Text.From(Number.From(_)), type text}})
```

Comment: Just tried this formula but it is replacing the entire cell with null

Comment: You were not clear that you wanted to remove the zeroes not the entire value.  Answer adjusted, try now

Comment: Sorry, re-reading my initial post I can see how you got that request. I just tried it and it seems to be hiding all the 0 and 00. 

Side note, I initially ran a step to hid all customers except one to apply this step to and wanted to unhide all customers on the next step. When running the formula you provided, I am stuck with the one visible customer.

TLDL I want to remove 0 & 00 from one customer PO only. Anyway to do this?

Comment: Filter for the customer. Apply the transform. Filter for all other customers. Combine the tables with x = Table1 & Table2 or Table.Combine({Table1,Table2})

Answer (score 1):

Two more possiblities;

- If all of `Customer PO` are integer numbers that are no longer than what you show (or no longer than the precision limit), you can merely, at the `#"Changed Type"` step, ensure that the column data type is set to `Int64.Type`
- If you need to retain the data type as `text`, then you can transform the column using the `Text.TrimStart` function:

  ```
  #"Trim Leading Zeros" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Previous Step",{"Customer PO", each Text.TrimStart(_,"0")})
  ```

Replace `#"Previous Step"` with the name of the previous step in your `M-Code`

Here is a code example you can paste into the `Advanced Editor` of PQ to demonstrate:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("PcqxDcAwCATAXahdPJA3uMwcFvuvETmyaE+3t7wyBDAHbeojNS4FsFQT2aTOQ7RoskMI0pv8X0BOqfoA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Customer Name" = _t, #"Customer PO" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Customer Name", type text}, {"Customer PO", type text}
        }),

    #"Trim Leading Zeros" = Table.TransformColumns(
        #"Changed Type",
            {"Customer PO", each Text.TrimStart(_,"0")})
in
    #"Trim Leading Zeros"
```

Comment: Not all customer POs are integers. Some have letters in them.

Initially I ran a step to hid all customers except one to apply the formula to and wanted to unhide all customers on the next step. When running the formula I am stuck with only the one visible customer. 

TLDL I want to remove 0 & 00 from one customer PO only. Anyway to do this?

Comment: @user21949225 I guess I am missing something. The code I supplied will remove leading zero's from any customer PO that has leading zero's, and leave everything else alone. Isn't that what you wanted?  In other words `00123` => `123` and `123456` => `123456`

Comment: @user21949225 I suppose if you only want to alter a single customer, you could do a row transform including that customer name in the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier answer to your question: Just convert the Column to Type "Whole Number". That removes all leading Zeros.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).